# running webpack upgrade to babel7 webpack3

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-plugin

please help me understand why bable/runtime/helpers cannot resolve interopRequireDefault. I have just upgraded babel, tried to explicitly move my dependencies to babel 7.0.0. As far as I understand if the browser is not detected as supporting latest babel uses from the supplied "plugins" in my babelrc file.

err is: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

my babel-loader is definitely calling on files and initiating a compilation. Do I need to specify some other config or traverse process?

devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-export-namespace-from": "7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode": "7.0.0-beta.34",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.34",
```

babelrc

```
  "presets": [
    "latest",
    "react",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode",
  ],
```

err

```
at Scope.moveBindingTo (/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/scope/index.js:939:12)
at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
at BlockScoping.run (node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `babel-preset-latest`, which has been deprecated in favour of [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env) (for Babel 7 it's `@babel/preset-env` on npm). The `latest` preset has been deprecated for a little while and Babel 7 dropped it entirely. The preset you are using is for Babel 6 and is incompatible with Babel 7.

You need to migrate to `@babel/preset-env`.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

The `env` preset can be configured to only transform features that are not supported by the browsers you target, but without any configuration it behaves exactly like the `latest` preset, so you can replace that in your `.babelrc`. Also, the `react` preset in your config should be `@babel/preset-react`.

```
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-react"
],
```